# Finding the correct 'record' and using ONLY the data from that record

Tags: sql

I have a list of products and suppliers.
I need to make sure that the Quantity is larger than zero.
If so, I need to find the product with the lowest price and list the supplier, the product (SKU), quantity and price.

My test data schema is:

```
create table products(merchant varchar(100), name varchar(150), quantity int, totalprice int);

insert into products values
  ('Supplier A', 'APC-SMT1000I', 10, 150),
  ('Supplier B', 'APC-SMT1000I', 15, 250), 
  ('Supplier C', 'APC-SMT1000I', 15, 350), 
  ('Supplier D', 'DEF-SMT1000I', 10, 500), 
  ('Supplier E', 'DEF-SMT1000I', 35, 350), 
  ('Supplier G', 'GHI-SMT1000I', 75, 70)
```

Logically, I would expect the result to read:

```
SUPPLIER    SKU          QTY        PRICE
Supplier A  APC-SMT1000I     10       150
Supplier D  DEF-SMT1000I     35           350
Supplier G  GHI-SMT1000I     75        70
```

My SQL Statement reads:

```
SELECT merchant AS Supplier, name AS sku,quantity AS Qty, 
min(totalprice) AS Price FROM products where quantity > 0 group by name;
```

My results are:

```
SUPPLIER    SKU          QTY        PRICE
Supplier A  APC-SMT1000I     10       150
Supplier D  DEF-SMT1000I     10           350
Supplier G  GHI-SMT1000I     75        70
```

Obviously, the coding is finding the lowest price and displaying it, but not with the correct data.

My Question?
How can I group the data, find the `record` with the lowest price and make sure the programme uses ONLY the data from that record?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following query:

```
SELECT products.*
FROM
  products INNER JOIN
  (SELECT name, MIN(totalprice) min_price
   FROM products
   WHERE quantity>0
   GROUP BY name) m
  ON products.name=m.name AND products.totalprice=min_price
```

In the subquery I calculate the minimum total price for every name, then I'm joining this subquery with the products table, to return only the rows that have the minimum total price for that name. If there are more than one row with the minimum price, they all will be shown.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61f19/4).

Comment: +1: You probably want to exclude the subquery columns from the output column list as they are duplicates anyway.

Comment: @RBarryYoung thanks :) yes i fixed the query to return just products.* , but it's possible to select just the columns that the OP needs

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is using window/analytic functions.  You don't specific the database you are using, but this is ANSI standard functionality available in most (but not all) databases.

Here is the syntax:

```
select merchant AS Supplier, name AS sku, quantity AS Qty, 
       totalprice AS Price
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name
                                order by totalprice
                               ) as seqnum
      from products p
      where quantity > 0
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified you RDBMS, so I'll provide a few queries.

This one should work in any database (but need 2 table scans):

```
select
    p.merchant as Supplier,
    p.name as sku,
    p.quantity as Qty, 
    p.totalprice as Price
from products as p
where
    p.totalprice in
    (
         select min(t.totalprice)
         from products as t
         where t.name = p.name
    )
```

This one should work for any RDBMS which have row_number window function:

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by name order by totalprice) as rn
    from products
)
select
    p.merchant as Supplier,
    p.name as sku,
    p.quantity as Qty, 
    p.totalprice as Price
from cte as p
where rn = 1
```

This one is for PostgreSQL:

```
select distinct on (p.name)
    p.merchant as Supplier,
    p.name as sku,
    p.quantity as Qty, 
    p.totalprice as Price
from products as p
order by p.name, p.totalprice
```

**=> <kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/61f19/7)</kbd>**